# '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>' on creating shared_ptr with custom deleter

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

I created the wrapper functors for SDL2 library methods to return smart pointers with custom deleters. It seems to work fine for unqiue_ptr (class Image) but gives following error for classes returning shared_ptr (class Window) during build:

`'<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>'`

The `SDL_CreateWindow` here returns raw `SDL_Window*` and the `IMG_Load` returns raw `SDL_Surface*`.

I have tried moving `Deleter` to public and removing copy restrictions of Window class, but still it fails with same error. Also, if I just return the `nullptr` from Window's function cast, it builds fine then. So the issue seems to be with the creation of the shared_ptr itself. What boggles me is why it works fine with `unique_ptr` but not `shared_ptr`.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Uncopyable.h"

// fails during build with error: '<function-style-cast>': 
// cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>'
class Window:private Uncopyable {
private:


public:
    class Deleter {
        void operator()(SDL_Window *window) {
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        }
    };

    static const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 800;
    static const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600;
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> operator()() const {
        return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(
            SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial",
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                SCREEN_WIDTH,
                SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN),
            Deleter());
    }
};

#pragma once
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include "Uncopyable.h"

// builds fine
class Image: private Uncopyable {
public:
    class Deleter{
        void operator()(SDL_Surface *image) {
            SDL_FreeSurface(image);
        }
    };

    std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, Deleter> operator()(const std::string &path) const {
        return std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, Deleter>(
            IMG_Load(path.c_str()),
            Deleter());
    }
};
```

Expected result: Window class should build without error like Image class

Actual result: Window class fails with error given above whereas Image class builds fine

**Update**: Narrowing down further by moving the the shared_ptr creation logic to simple function, I found that removing the custom `Deleter()` removes build error. So it seems to be the culprit. But I need the Deleter and also, why same contruct works fine with Image using unique_ptr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slimmed your example down a little:

```cpp
#include <memory>

// Stub these out since we don't have them available and they don't really matter
// for the substance of the question.
struct SDL_Window {};
void SDL_DestroyWindow( SDL_Window* win ) { delete win; }
SDL_Window* SDL_CreateWindow() { return new SDL_Window{}; }

// fails during build with error: '<function-style-cast>': 
// cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>'
class Window {
public:
    class Deleter {
        void operator()(SDL_Window *window) {
            SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        }
    };

    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> operator()() const {
        return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(
            SDL_CreateWindow(),
            Deleter());
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto win = Window();
    auto sp = win();
}
```

Now the problem is more apparent:

```
/usr/local/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:642:11: error: 
  'void Window::Deleter::operator()(SDL_Window*)' is private within this context
        __d(__p); // Call _Deleter on __p.
        ~~~^~~~~

main.cpp:16:14: note: declared private here
         void operator()(SDL_Window *window) {
```

See it fail live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6be301f4bc174bf7)</kbd>.

If you add `public` to your deleter class or make it a struct, it will work. But, you could also skip that class and just pass in the deleting function directly if that's all the work it needs to do (or use a lambda if it's a bit more complicated):

```cpp
    std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> operator()() const {
        return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(
            SDL_CreateWindow(),
            SDL_DestroyWindow);
    }

    // Or with a lambda if it's more complicated (here also using a factory func)
    static std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> Create() {
        return std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window>(
            SDL_CreateWindow(),
            [] (auto win) { 
                UnregisterMyWindow( win );
                SDL_DestroyWindow( win ); 
             });
    }
```

See it work live on <kbd>[Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4d5a93ab93cd89bd)</kbd>.

Also, it is of questionable wisdom to use `Window::operator()` like that. I'd suggest you make a non-member or static member factory function instead to make windows.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I was just then going to ask you why it works for Image class (returning unique_ptr), but rebuilding again with your fix, I got more explicit error by compiler this time:
```
Error C2248 'Image::Deleter::operator ()': cannot access private member declared in class 'Image::Deleter' SDLGame 
```
so it needed `public` too :) . Why compiler didn't threw clear warning for shared_ptr is mystery still.

Comment: Template errors can often be overwhelming, and it's hard to find the signal amidst the noise. I'd blame that. :-)

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the flaw in the design. It didn't occur to me use the function directly. I will go with the first factory approach you suggested.

Comment: You're welcome. I added a factory function to the last code snippet above (and to the last Coliru link, which makes use of it). PS, thanks for accepting this as the answer. If you want to show extra love, you can also up-vote my answer. :-)

Comment: I had up-voted. But as my rep<15, it doesn't show publicly, though it seems to be recorded.Thanks for the snippet too.